# Converting MySQL to SQLite for iOS Device to download and use it possible?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, sqlite

I'm working with a large Database and I need my app able to works offline.

I'm new to iOS Developer, I have read a lot of tutorial from books but still un-expierience.

**My set up is:**

1. PHP&MySQL Webserver
2. Use it only in Local Area Network, not going online to internet.

**My App should be:**

1. Download the latest content from Server and store to device memory (or what so ever)
2. Able to do CRUD on those data I have download while the device is offline (this is serve because when the user isn't in the Wifi Area, so I plan it to make offline)
3. When in the Wifi area, I can update my change back to the server

**My 1st Plan is:**

Retrieve my data via JSON format from the PHP server and Store it to iOS Core Data and then upload only the change back to the server via NSUrl post or something.. i'm not sure

**My 2nd Plan is:**

I want to convert MySQL to SQLite so it should be 1 file and download it to iOS so the work load is on the server not on the iOS Device and use the same NSUrl post it back to server and update it.

---

**My app flow should be like this:**

Start:

...

1. Check whether any data need to upload ?

   1.1 Yes, Upload the data: Goto:2

   1.2 No: Goto:2
2. Download the Database in to Device Memories.
3. User Login.

...

I'm thinking I should go on my 2nd solution, I think conversion from MySQL to SQLite isn't too hard to do it but how do I check when iOS device ask for the file and don't know that the file have complete the conversion ?

or

Any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You should download the database as a json array, write it to a local sqlite database and write you changes simultaneously to another table. When you need to upload changes, read from your duplicate table containing only the changes and update your mysql db on the server. You can use FMDB (see below) to help with sqlite on ios.

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb